# How to get a hex value from a decimal integer in Java?

Tags: java, hex, int

I don't know how to generate a hex "0x83" character from an integer value in Java.

I need a "0x83" value to represent a letter in the Cyrillic alphabet (this letter: **ѓ**), in order to send it (the letter) to my printer. When converting 131 (0x83 in decimal) into hex with my converter (below) I get three numbers: 0x31, 0x33 and 0x31.

```
public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(arg.getBytes()));
}
```

I need to get 0x83 from this conversion.

Comment: It's entirely unclear exactly what you're doing. It sounds like you're converting the *string* "131" to bytes, which isn't the same thing at all. Please show sample code.

Comment: I send parameter which is integer and after adding 128 to get value greater then 128 => 131 and convert but its wrong. Because i can't insert Cyrillic alphabet in eclipse and convert.

Comment: public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(arg.getBytes()));
}

Comment: Then what most of the answers here say i.e., `Integer.toHexString` should solve your problem!

Comment: @Gogoo: Don't put the code in comments - edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: You claim that you "send parameter which is integer" but the code you've provided in the comment takes a *string* parameter, not an integer. Please be precise, otherwise it'll be hard to help you.

Comment: No, because I use this method for all other function in my program.

Comment: Ok to be precise which parameter I need to send to my method in comment to get 0x83. Or how to send to get 0x83. Because that parameter I can't insert in my program here is link http://www.ascii.ca/cp1251.htm

Comment: Ok so you want to send one parameter to printer that returns 0x83 in return. Reply hurry.

Comment: I wnat to send one parameter to my method( public String toHex(String arg) { return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(arg.getBytes())); } ) which will convert the input parameter and return 0x83.

Comment: Or I need to change encoding table? Or method but other character to stay the same like before.

Comment: Is this because I need more than 1 byte to present (ѓ).

Comment: I try like this: toHex(""+(char)131); but I get 0x3f.

Comment: Do you really want to send the hexadecimal string `"0x83"` to your printer, or do you want to send the byte with this value `0x83 = 131` to your printer?

Answer (score 43):

If you are trying to convert integer 131 to a hex string, you can try

```
Integer.toHexString( 131 )
```

It will return "83" as String.

Answer (score 13):

Here's one example:

```
String str = Integer.toHexString(131);
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(arg.getBytes()));
} I use this converter...

Comment: @Gogoo :- Just debug the code and watch the line arg.getBytes() it generates ascii values for each digit hence the output comes 31,33,31.

Comment: I need to get 0x83. Or how to send and what value to get 0x83. Because (ѓ) I can't insert in my program here is link http://ascii.ca/cp1251.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
String cyrillic = Character.toString((char)0x83)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking out the [Java Integer API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29). Here are a couple of [examples:](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/ConvertingIntegertoHexString.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem, when converting:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(131));
```

returns 83.

Comment: public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(arg.getBytes()));
} I use this converter...

Comment: @Gogoo Can you try with `String.format("%x", Integer.parseInt(s))`

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities, either your printer needs 0x83 as a byte or as string/char

Send as a byte:

```
int Cyrillic_int = 131; 
byte Cyrillic = (byte) Cyrillic_int;
```

Or send a string representation of 0x83:

```
int Cyrillic_int = 131;
String Cyrillic = Integer.toHexString(131);
```