# Java Convert integer to hex integer

Tags: java, integer, hex

I'm trying to convert a number from an integer into an another integer which, if printed in hex, would look the same as the original integer.

For example:

Convert 20 to 32 (which is 0x20)

Convert 54 to 84 (which is 0x54)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get hex value from integer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258415/how-to-get-hex-value-from-integer-in-java)

Comment: I just realised now that to actually solve the given test cases, it is to convert **hex to int**, not the other way around. However, the question title that says "Java Convert integer to hex integer" has led many answers including mine and the most upvoted one to converting **int to hex**.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
public static int convert(int n) {
  return Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n), 16);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(convert(20));  // 32
  System.out.println(convert(54));  // 84
}
```

That is, treat the original number as if it was in hexadecimal, and then convert to decimal.

Comment: Converting from 4 bytes to a string, then from string to an int and then to hex? No, thanks.

Comment: This solution is flawed. Try to run the following:  Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(-2115381772), 16) - this returns a NumberFormatException.

Comment: This converts a number in base 16 to its representation in base 10. [Correct answer is below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9321597/2823516)

Answer (score 257):

The easiest way is to use `Integer.toHexString(int)`

Comment: The question was to convert from integer to integer, not integer to string. Please read the question again.

Comment: That doesn't make sense though, you can't control the integer's internal representation. If you want something in hex, you're by definition asking about a _human readable_ representation.

Comment: @sircodesalot: The question is about calculating an integer with a certain property _if_ printed as hex, which is a purely mathematical conversion. I strongly disagree with Jossef that an answer should be marked as correct based on google results, but according to the votes, I seem to be in the minority.

Comment: @AdamNybäck rekt

Answer (score 13):

Another way to convert **int to hex**.

`String hex = String.format("%X", int);`

You can change capital `X` to `x` for lowercase.

**Example:**

`String.format("%X", 31)` results `1F`.

`String.format("%X", 32)` results `20`.

Comment: `String hex = String.format("%02X", int);` for fixed length (two characters with eventual leading zeros).

Answer (score 7):

```
int orig = 20;
int res = Integer.parseInt(""+orig, 16);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this (the way you would do it on paper):

```
public static int solve(int x){
    int y=0;
    int i=0;

    while (x>0){
        y+=(x%10)*Math.pow(16,i);
        x/=10;
        i++;
    }
    return y;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(solve(20));
    System.out.println(solve(54));
}
```

For the examples you have given this would calculate: 0*16^0+2*16^1=32 and 4*16^0+5*16^1=84

Answer (score 4):

```
String input = "20";
int output = Integer.parseInt(input, 16); // 32
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is optimized iff you only want to print the hexa representation of a *positive* integer.

It should be blazing fast as it uses only bit manipulation, the utf-8 values of ASCII chars and recursion to avoid reversing a `StringBuilder` at the end.

```
public static void hexa(int num) {
    int m = 0;
    if( (m = num >>> 4) != 0 ) {
        hexa( m );
    }
    System.out.print((char)((m=num & 0x0F)+(m<10 ? 48 : 55)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
public static int specialNum(num){

    return Integer.parseInt( Integer.toString(num) ,16)
}
```

It should convert any special decimal integer to its hexadecimal counterpart.