# How to fputc a decimal to hex?

Tags: java, c++, c, hex, decimal

I am trying to display a decimal as a hex. If I have a decimal such as 3703484078, how can I use fputc to display it as hex DCBEAEAE? Is there some formula that I could use?

Comment: Try using `fprintf(myfile, "%4X", 3703484078);`

Comment: look to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465098/decimal-to-hexadecimal-converter-in-java) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Call the input number X.
2. Call a string S that is initially blank.
3. Compute X mod 16.
4. Convert the answer you got from the previous step to a character using the following mapping: 0->'0' 1->'1' 2->'2' 3->'3' 4->'4' 5->'5' 6->'6' 7->'7' 8->'8', 9->'9' 10->'A' 11->'B' 12->'C' 13->'D' 14->'E' 15->'F'.
5. Replace string S with the character you just got followed by the current contents of string S.
6. Divide X by 16 (using integer division), store the result in X
7. If X is not zero, go to step 3.
8. Output string S from left to right using `fputc`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the number to a string of hexadecimal text digits.

Search StackOverflow for "hex conversion" or "hex printing" for details.