# Convert RGB to Hex using java code - Android

Tags: java, android, hex, converters, rgb

I'm converting RGB to Hexadecimal Colors using this code. I have 3 Edittext to input R, G and B. Now what I want to do is to convert it without using the API. Like converting and computing it with my own code and not by toHexString(). can someone help me to do that? Thanks a lot. Here is my code.

```
      convert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                final int r = Integer.parseInt(showRed.getText().toString());
                final int g = Integer.parseInt(showGreen.getText().toString());
                final int b = Integer.parseInt(showBlue.getText().toString());

                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append("#");
                builder.append(Integer.toHexString(r)); // Real computation here
                builder.append(Integer.toHexString(g)); // Real computation here
                builder.append(Integer.toHexString(b)); // Real computation here

                result.setText(builder.toString());

            }
        });
```

Comment: so actually you need conversion from base 10 to base 16 that is decimal to hexadecimal?

Comment: Didn't I spend a LOT of time helping you with this a couple of days ago?  Do you want somebody else to go through the same process all over again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607858/how-to-convert-a-rgb-color-value-to-an-hexadecimal-value-in-java

Comment: First, can you tell the reason why you want to do it without using API? Anyway, [here is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13465128/2821954)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `r`, `g` and `b` values in the range [0, 255]:

```
String hexColor = String.format( "#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b );
```

Read [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) javadoc for more formatting options.

Comment: this works but I want to use the real computation. Like with the operators and remainders etc.. Can you help me with that? :(

Answer (score 2):

So you want to do it without toHexString for some reason...

What you're looking for is a way to convert a base 10 number to a base 16 number. You want to code it yourself, but not actually code it yourself obviously, since you're here. Right?

Divide the number by 16. Convert the remainder to Hex if greater than 9 by;

```
if(number > 9) {
    switch(number) {
        case 10: string remainderPlaceholder = "A";
        break;

        case 11: string remainderPlaceholder = "B";
        break;
```

Etcetera, you get the idea.

Then take your quotient from the first part and, if greater than 16, divide it by 16 again, take the remainder and convert it to hex again using the selfsame switch statement mentioned above.

Lather, rinse, and repeat, appending each new answer to the front of the string, until you've got the full value.

Example: 255/16 = 15r15
15 (converted to hex using the above switch) = "F";
And again.

Now one more example, with the number 146:

146/16 = 9r2

Converting to hex: 92.

Let me know if you actually want me to write out the code for you. But if you do, you may as well just use toHexString() since it'll be more efficient than whatever I write for you, and since you wouldn't be writing the code yourself either way...

**Edit: some pseudo-ish code so you can figure out how to code it:**

```
int redMain = r/16;
int redRemainder = r%16;
//(do the same thing for green and blue)
int redFirst = redMain/16;
```

Then put the case statement like above into a function and call it on the two things in a row like

```
public void makeHex(number) {
    if(number > 9) {
        switch(number) {
            case 10: string remainderPlaceholder = "A";
            break;

            case 11: string remainderPlaceholder = "B";
            break;
//etcetera
```

Which you'd call like
    makeHex(redMain);

And then you just have to append the strings in the right order, so it would look like;

```
String redValue = makeHex(redMain).toString();
redValue = redValue + makeHex(redMain).toString();
```

And then put them all together with a hashtag like

```
String finalHex = "#" + redValue + greenValue + blueValue;
```

Not too hard.

But I would seriously just use toHexString since there are likely a bunch of things wrong with this way of doing it.

Comment: can you write the code for me? I'm having trouble with this. Please :(

Comment: Added in a mini-tutorial on how to write the code, should guide you through the process nicely.