# How to convert Decimal Value to hexadecimal in java?

Tags: java, hex, decimal, data-conversion

How to convert Decimal Value (Temperature) to 16 bit hexadecimal in java?

input : -54.9

Expected Result : 0x8225

I have reverse code for it where i am converting 16 byte hexadecimal to Decimal Value (Temperature).

```
private static double hexDataToTemperature(String tempHexData) {

    String tempMSBstr = tempHexData.substring(0, 2);
    String tempLSBstr = tempHexData.substring(2, 4);

    int tempMSB = Integer.parseInt(tempMSBstr, 16);
    int tempLSB = Integer.parseInt(tempLSBstr, 16);
    int sign = 1;

    if (tempMSB >= 128) {
        tempMSB = tempMSB - 128;
        sign = -1;
    }

    Float f = (float) (sign * ((float) ((tempMSB * 256) + tempLSB) / 10));

    return Double.parseDouble("" + f);

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465098/decimal-to-hexadecimal-converter-in-java

Comment: first is good idea search it in the stackoverflow database

Comment: @Stultuske Here we should use what Java provides so this particular link does not help.

Comment: I don't think this will work because I need to convert like -25.5 value into hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To represent temperatures in tenths of a degree as a signed short (16 bit) value represented in hexadecimal:

```
static String toHex( float t ){
    short it = (short)Math.round(t*10);
    return String.format( "%04x", it );
}
```

You can add "0x" to the format string if you want that. - The reverse conversion:

```
static float toDec( String s ){
    int it = Integer.parseInt( s, 16 );
    if( it > 32767 ) it -= 65536;
    return it/10.0F;
}
```

This represents the integer in two's complement, so the result for -54.9 will *not* be 0x8225 but 0xfddb. Using the most significant bit as a sign bit and representing the absolute value in the remaining 15 bit ("signed magnitude") is highly unusual especially with Java.

If you do want to use signed magnitude:

```
static String toHex( float t ){
    int sign = 0;
    if( t < 0 ){
        sign = 0x8000;
        t = -t;
    }
    short it = (short)(Math.round(t*10) + sign);
    return String.format( "%04x", it );
}

static float toDec( String s ){
    int it = Integer.parseInt( s, 16 );
    if( it > 32767 ){
        it = -(it - 0x8000);
    }
    return it/10.0F;
}
```

Comment: @launa : it is not working for me.
I am passing input f: -54.9 but

Expected Result : 0x8225

Comment: but i am getting fbbd as result.

Comment: Please read what I wrote. Do you insist on this unusual representation?

Comment: @AnkitKesarwani I've added the methods for signed magnitude.

Comment: @ laune : updated solution work for me. Thanks a lot laune. :)

Answer (score -1):

try Idea from this code " please notice toHexString()"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    class DecimalToHex
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
          Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
          System.out.print(" decimal number : ");
          int num =input.nextInt();

          // calling method toHexString()
          String str = Integer.toHexString(num);
          System.out.println("Decimal to hexadecimal: "+str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but where I should pass the value that i need to convert?

Comment: and input is float or double

Comment: by using scanner the console will ask u to enter a value
then u can specify what type it will take if double then
double num =input.nextDouble();
[see link](http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html).

Comment: @user3624028 And then the Integer.toHexString( num ) will do... what?

Comment: Integer.toHexString( num ) will method returns a hexadecimal string representation of int, you can also assign it to double type, for example :  
 `Double d = new Double("4.0");
String str = d.toHexString(1.0);
     System.out.println("Hex String = " + str);`