# Integer to hex String NumberformatException

Tags: java, int, hex, numberformatexception

I wanted to convert integer values to hex strings. I quickly searched stackoverflow and did it the [following way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321553/java-convert-integer-to-hex-integer) (as the accepted solution indicated - however didn't look careful enough):

```
Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n), 16);
```

However when trying to convert

```
 Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(-2115381772), 16)
```

it throws an `NumberFormatException`. **So out of curiosity - why is the NumberFormatException thrown?**

(Afterwards I changed the code to `Integer.toHexString(-2115381772)` and everything is working as expected.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because,

`Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(-2115381772), 16)` considers `-2115381772` value in Hexadecimal (16) base, and that is outside of range for `int` value. So you are getting that exception.

`Integer.toHexString(-2115381772)` considers `-2115381772` value in decimal base, and it is in range of `int` value.

Answer (score 2):

`-2115381772` as hex does not fit in an Integer.

Try `Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(-2115381772), 16);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum value of `int` is `-2147483648`.

So when you give any values less than `-80000000`, `NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

Because `Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(-80000000), 16)` gives `-2147483648` as output, which is the minimum value of `int`.

Comment: Don't understand it fully. -2115381772 < -2147483648 thus a perfectly valid int. However Meraman explained it...

Comment: Well you provided the value ``-2115381772`` in hex and that's ``-142089918322`` decimal which is certainly smaller than ``-2147483648`` (and btw. ``-2115381772 > -2147483648``).