# Java int to hex with 0x

Tags: java, hex, zero

I'm trying to convert int to hex with format 0x12 0x2B and so on. Is there anything similar like python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex
to accomplish this or i will need to work around this with many unnecessary steps?

I need to get something like this below:

```
int []hexInt={0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x01};
```

Comment: Do you mean you want a `String` representation of the number as hex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Convert integer to hex integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321553/java-convert-integer-to-hex-integer)

Comment: I need int as show int [] hexInt={0x00 and so on}

Comment: it is not duplicate. I can convert integer to hex but i can not convert it to hex like 0x1b. If i use 1B insted of 0x1B then i'm not getting what i need.

Comment: Shown where? I don't understand your goal. Are you declaring an `int[]` or you want to display those characters?

Comment: Your array is just an ordinary array of `int`s.  The fact that you have typed them using hex literals is dealt with by the compiler and gone at run-time.

Comment: I know that. But when i send to smpp commands like int it isnt working but when send commands like 0x00 evrything works fine. So i know what i need.

Comment: And that command is Enquire Link

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  It is not even clear to me whether you want a string or an integer.

Comment: How you write value of int doesn't really matter, it will still represent same number. If you use array with `{0x10, 16}` will contain same numbers. Please provide more details about what you want to achieve. Do you wan to print decimal int like `16` as hexadecimal `0x10`?

Comment: Ok i'm writing it to a socket. I'm using DataOutputStream when i type manualy like in above example: int []hexInt={0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x01}; output.write(hexInt[i]); i'm getting response from smpp server enquireLink response if i use it with out 0x it is not recognized. So i dont want to type it every time i need to send data to the smpp server.

Comment: @ 5gon12ederyou are right i sent int and got response dunno why did i mess with hex. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could declare a `String` which will be equal to `"0x" + Integer.toHexString(int)`

Comment: i did that but when i want to parse string to int it can not parse 0x1b to int it throws number format exception but it accept array int [] hexInt={0x1b} i'm confused.

Comment: Do what I said above and then store it that way `Integer.parseInt(num.substring(2), 16);`. This will remove the `0x` from the string before parsing.

Comment: @Anak1n To parse hexString back you decimal int you need to remove `0x` part and provide radix like `Integer.parseInt("100",16)` will be parsed to `256`.

Comment: `Integer.decode` will actually properly handle the 0x prefix.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String intToHexStr(int i){
    return "0x"+String.format("%2s", Integer.toHexString(i)).replace(' ', '0');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is very late but here is the answer to your question:

```
Integer.parseInt(String.format("%X", intValue),16)
```