# inserting String value of byte array in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I have a byte array as shown below,

```
byte b1[] = {-127, -87, -32, -112};
```

when I'm trying to convert it to a String it's showing black diamond like character, I want to insert it in the database.

**Which charset should I use for database?**

I have tried `utf8mb4` and `CP1250`? I'm using `mysql version 5.7.14` ?

Given below error while inserting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD...' for column
```

Here is the code:

```
   byte b1[] = {-127, -87, -32, -112};
   TRNRequest tr = new TRNRequest();
   tr.set(new String(b1));
   trnRequestService.saveTransactionRequest(tr);
```

`trnRequestService` is *dao layer service* which stores object in database and `TRNRequest` is my class, I am using *Hibernate* for database connection. I want to read this character

```
public class DbByteInsert {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             System.out.println(new String(new byte[]{ 48, 50}));
             System.out.println(new String(new byte[]{ -127, -87, -32, -112}));
        }
}
```

check this example I am able to insert first byte array in db but I can not insert second..!

Comment: How can anyone guess ur encoding, provide  atleast code where from you got this?

Comment: Please provide your code here.

Comment: How you are converting byte[] to string. Use Arrays.toString(b1) to convert array into string and insert the resulted string into database

Comment: I am using UTF8 charset

Comment: How are you inserting the data? Where's your code? Why do you let us guess what the real problem is?

Comment: Getting black diamonds means that the bytes cannot be decoded to a string. *You're losing data when you convert to string.* What are you trying to do? If you want to insert binary data into a database, you can, just don't try to convert to a string.

Comment: yes it's generating \x  like  characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Convert integer to hex integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321553/java-convert-integer-to-hex-integer)

Comment: I have added part of my code, I want to insert String into database, I am receiving this byte array from server which I want to read...!

Comment: it's packed binary data in Hex format

Comment: @AxelH actually it's opposite Hex Integer to Integer

Comment: use Arrays.toString(b1) instead of new String(b1) to convert it into string

Comment: @Rajashekhar it's giving the same array in string format as              [-127, -87, -32, -112]

Comment: Ok, add an example of _input -> encode -> output_ This is not clear. From what I can see, you will not store what you want. Forget about the Database for now, your String is incorrect. I see 4byte and a String much longer.

Comment: When you not pass any charset to string constructor it takes platform default charset. check once by passing charset database is using to string constructor

Comment: @AxelH check the example

Comment: An what is the output of those and the expect result? You are converting a negative byte into a character (basicly) ...

Comment: { 48, 50} gives 0 2 and {-127, -87, -32, -112} black diamond like chars

Comment: And **the expect result** ? -127 is not an UNICODE value