# How to format numbers to a hex strings?

Tags: java, formatting

I want to format int numbers as hex strings.  `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(1));` prints `1` but I want it as `0x00000001`. How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get hex value from integer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258415/how-to-get-hex-value-from-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try this

```
System.out.println(String.format("0x%08X", 1));
```

Comment: this works, with this method we can print long (8 bytes)
like: 0xFFFFFFFF8DF6AE78

Answer (score 28):

You can use the String.format to format an integer as a hex string.

```
   System.out.println(String.format("0x%08X", 1));
```

That is, pad with zeros, and make the total width 8. The 1 is converted to hex for you. The above line gives: `0x00000001` and

```
   System.out.println(String.format("0x%08X", 234));
```

gives: `0x000000EA`

Answer (score 7):

From formatting syntax documented on Java's [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class:

```
Integer intObject = Integer.valueOf(1);
String s = String.format("0x%08x", intObject);
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 5):

Less verbose:

```
System.out.printf("0x%08x", 1); //"Use %0X for upper case letters
```

Answer (score 3):

##### Java 17+

There is a new immutable class dedicated to conversion into and formatting hexadecimal numbers. The easiest way to go is using [`HexFormat::toHexDigits`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html#toHexDigits(int)) which includes leading zeroes:

```
String hex = "0x" + HexFormat.of().toHexDigits(1);
// 0x00000001
```

**Beware**, one has to concatenate with the `"0x"` prefix as such method ignores defined prefixes and suffixes, so the following snippet doesn't work as expected (only [`HexFormat::formatHex`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html#formatHex(byte%5B%5D)) methods work with them):

```
String hex = HexFormat.of().withPrefix("0x").toHexDigits(1);
// 00000001
```

> Returns the eight hexadecimal characters for the int value. Each nibble `(4 bits)` from most significant to least significant of the value is formatted as if by `toLowHexDigit(nibble)`. **The delimiter, prefix and suffix are not used.**

**Alternatively** use the advantage of [`HexFormat::formatHex`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html#formatHex(byte%5B%5D)) formatting to two hexadecimal characters, and a `StringBuilder` as an `Appendable` prefix containing `"0x"`:

> Each byte value is formatted as the prefix, **two hexadecimal characters** selected from uppercase or lowercase digits, and the suffix.

```
StringBuilder hex = HexFormat.of()
    .formatHex(new StringBuilder("0x"), new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 1});
// 0x00000001
```

```
StringBuilder hex = HexFormat.of()
    .formatHex(new StringBuilder("0x"), ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(1).array());
// 0x00000001
```

Comment: Good to know this new addition in Java-17. It shows how strongly Java has been evolving.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java too intimately, but there must be a way you can pad the output from the toHexString function with a '0' to a length of 8.  If "0x" will always be at the beginning, just tack on that string to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Just use "Integer.toString(n,x).toUpperCase()" where n=Number, x= the Base

```
Integer.toString(123,16).toUpperCase()  //7B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) or [the printf method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) on a PrintStream.

Answer (score 0):

This is String extension for Kotlin

```
//if lengthOfResultTextNeeded = 3 and input String is "AC", the result is = "0AC"
//if lengthOfResultTextNeeded = 4 and input String is "AC", the result is = "00AC"

fun String.unSignedHex(lengthOfResultTextNeeded: Int): String {
    val count =
        lengthOfResultTextNeeded - this.length 
    val buildHex4DigitString = StringBuilder()
    var i = 1
    while (i <= count) {
        buildHex4DigitString.append("0")
        ++i
    }
    return buildHex4DigitString.toString() + this
}
```